# What is OpenGL ES Shading Language based on and what are the differences?

Tags: opengl-es

My guess is that it is derived from version 1.10 of the OpenGL Shading Language, document revision number 59. Found it here, page 7:
http://old.siggraph.org/publications/2006cn/course16/KhronosSpecs/ESLanguageSpec1.10.11.pdf
The differences are also listed there with underlined text.

Can anyone confirm that it is based on version 1.10?

I took a look into the latest revision of OpenGL ES Shading Language - 1.0.17. It seems there is no reference to the original OpenGL Shading Language and no difference specs at all. The problem is that I can't find any document revisions between 1.10.11 and 1.0.17. They could change their mind and derive ES Shading Language from Shading Language 1.20. or something else.

Comment: -1: For poor research. The PDF you claim to have looked at answers your questions in the intro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I took a look into the latest revision of OpenGL ES Shading Language

Are you sure you did? Because the [PDF of the 1.0.17 spec](http://www.khronos.org/registry/gles/specs/2.0/GLSL_ES_Specification_1.0.17.pdf) very clearly states, in the Introduction:

> The OpenGL ES Shading Language (also known as GLSL ES or ESSL) is based on the OpenGL Shading Language (GLSL) version 1.20.

Following this is a detailed change log of every revision of the spec.

Furthermore, what does it matter what it is based on? It copies and modifies the GLSL specification; you don't need to look at any particular GLSL spec to read the ESSL spec.

Comment: Shame on me! I overlooked the introduction. It's obvious:(
The reason I am doing this is that one part of my thesis is to briefly describe the differences between OpenGL ES 2.0 and OpenGL. Anyway, many thanks to you!